# Using ssize_t vs int

Tags: c, type-conversion, standards

### Code

I've got a function which I can write in *one* of four possible ways:

```c
    int do_or_die(int retval);
    int do_or_die(ssize_t retval);
    ssize_t do_or_die(int retval);   
    ssize_t do_or_die(ssize_t retval);
```

---

And then it will be called with *both* of these ways for library functions:

```c
    written = do_or_die(write(...)); // POSIX write returns ssize_t
    printed = do_or_die(printf(...)); // printf returns int
```

### Questions

- Which prototype should I use?
- What types should I give to `written` and `printed`?

I want to have the most robust and standard code, while still having just one `do_or_die` function.

I am using C99 in this case, but if answer is different for C11, then I'd like to know that too, for future.

Comment: Since `ssize_t` may well be wider than `int` you should probably go with the fourth prototype.

Comment: @PaulR Is that guaranteed, or might `int` also be wider than `ssize_t`?

Comment: @delnan: I don't think that's possible, although they may be equal.

Comment: @PaulR Well, I can imagine an architecture where int is wider: Segmented memory a la 16 bit x86 (so ssize_t is 16 bit), with 32 bit integers. The question is really whether the relevant standards (some version of C, and in this case POSIX) guarantee anything.

Comment: Thanks all for insight! I think in the real code I will do `int do_or_die(intmax_t retval);` and exit cleanly if it does not fit, because the return value not fitting in an `int` is purely theoretical due to certain physical limitations of the system.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There's no guarantee in the POSIX standard that `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(ssize_t)`, nor the other way around. Typically `ssize_t` is larger than `int`, but the safe and portable option in C99 is to use `intmax_t` instead for the argument and the return value.

The only guarantees you have wrt. the relationship between `int` and `ssize_t` are:

- `int` can store values of at least the range [-2^15 ... 2^15-1] per ISO C
- `ssize_t` can store values of at least the range [-1 ... 2^15-1] [per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) (see also [`_POSIX_SSIZE_MAX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html)).

(Interestingly, there isn't even a guarantee that `ssize_t` can store the negative counterparts of its positive range. It's not a signed `size_t`, but a "size type" with an error value.)

Comment: `ssize_t` is actually not specified at all in the C standard. It's part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: The link for ssize_t only mentions the max size, and nothing more, not even the signedness. Can you provide a reference for that? Thank you.

Comment: I've only just discovered that `int_fast64_t` exists in C++11. I'm tempted to use it as my default integer type "fastest signed integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Like what @2501 said, can you please post more reference about the minimum value as the reference you posted doesn't say anything about the minimum.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid What you wrote seems unrelated to what is being discussed here. As for your temptation to use `int_fast64_t`, I'd recommend using that only if you need at least 64 bits, which isn't a common use case. Something like `int_fast32_t` should work in most situations. It'll be the fastest signed integer on your platform with at least 32 bits (it might be 64 bits though).

Answer (score 5):

Use types in a way:

- you don't mix `signed` and `unsigned` types together and
- you don't truncate values from larger types while storing them in smaller types (overflow/underflow)

`ssize_t` might be an alias for `int`, yet it is not standard C and might be environment specific.

If your program will run in specific environment, check whether `sizeof(ssize_t) <= sizeof(int)` and use `int`. Otherwise, use some other type `T` where `sizeof(T)` is greater or equal than both `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(ssize_t)`.

Comment: `ssize_t` is not an alias for `int` on x86-64 systems.

Comment: @larsmans: I've rephrased it into "might be an alias for `int`" :)

Comment: I think, for practical reasons, `ssize_t` would be at least the same size as a pointer, or there will be an unreasonable limitation on max write size. But I guess there's no guarantee that size of pointer is >= size of int, or is there?

Comment: @hyde: typically, `ssize_t` is the signed counterpart of `size_t`, but POSIX doesn't even guarantee that.

Comment: @larsmans Yeah, I guess an argument could be made for a 32 bit OS to have `size_t` 32 bits, but `ssize_t` wider, to avoid being limited to writing/reading only half of address space...

Comment: @hyde: the other way around would make more sense to me, since you can't have an array larger than `SIZE_MAX` :) Also `ssize_t` is mostly used in I/O functions, which may have limitations beyond those of the processor and MMU.

Comment: @larsmans Well, `write` returns `ssize_t`, but takes `size_t` parameter (as does `malloc`), so things would get hairy for large writes, if return value might overflow. This isn't all theoretical either, considering there are 32 bit systems with 4 gigs of installed memory.

Comment: @hyde: usually, though, a single process cannot acquire more than 2GB of memory (except through special interfaces) and thus cannot write more than that in a single system call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use int or long int data types, however `ssize_t` is a system data type that should be used for cross-platform portability. The fundamental types (such as 'int') can be different sizes on different implementations. Usually what happens is the system type (in this case `ssize_t`) takes advantage of C's typedef feature so that the machine-specific data type size is used, e.g. `typedef signed ssize_t` (this is part of SUSv3 standard data types). It is good practice to use system data types, where possible, when implementing any kind of system-level programming.

For a more detailed description refer to The Linux Programming Interface (Michael Kerrisk)