# calling recv() results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, segmentation-fault

I'm making a chat program with a tcp connection on my linux machine. I had a working program to send text to the server and receive the data back, but when I use the exact same line with recv(), I get a segmentation fault. The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>     // for strlen()
#include <stdlib.h>     // for exit()
#include <sys/socket.h> // for send() and recv()
#include <unistd.h>     // for sleep(), close()
#include <iostream>

#include "Auxiliary.h"
#include "CreateTCPClientSocket.h"

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32   /* Size of receive buffer */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int         sock;                   /* Socket descriptor */
    char *      echoString;             /* String to send to echo server */
    char *      tempString;             /* String to save the cin */
    char        echoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE + 1]; /* Buffer for received string */
    int         echoStringLen;          /* Length of string to echo */
    int         bytesRcvd;              /* Bytes read in single recv() */

    bool end = false;

    parse_args (argc, argv);

    sock = CreateTCPClientSocket (argv_ip, argv_port);

    while (!end)
    {
        bool messageGet = false;
        std::cout << "What's your message:" << std::endl;
        while(!messageGet)
        {
            std::cin >> tempString;
            if(tempString != "")
            {
                echoString = tempString;
                messageGet = true;
            }
        }

        echoStringLen = strlen(echoString);          /* Determine input length */
        echoString[echoStringLen] = '\0'; 
        echoStringLen += 2;
        delaying();

        send(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0);

        info_s("Sent string:", echoString);

        // TODO: add code to receive & display the converted string from the server
        //       use recv()
        bytesRcvd = recv(sock, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE-1, 0);
        std::cout << echoBuffer << std::endl;
    }

    delaying ();

    close (sock);
    info ("close & exit");
    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: bytesRcvd shoud be ssize_t type.
See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224655/using-ssize-t-vs-int

Comment: I changed it and the is no difference, I still get the segmentation fault when I receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How sure are you that the segfault is in `recv()`?

Your call to `recv()` looks fine, however, an earlier line is writing into unallocated memory which will cause a segfault:

```
std::cin >> tempString;
```

Try declaring `tempString` like this:

```
#define INPUT_BUF_SIZE 100
char tempString[INPUT_BUF_SIZE + 1];
```

Furthermore, this code seems unusual:

```
echoStringLen = strlen(echoString);          /* Determine input length */
echoString[echoStringLen] = '\0'; 
echoStringLen += 2;
```

`echoString` will already be null terminated, otherwise `strlen()` would not return the correct result. Since it is already null terminated, adding `\0` achieves nothing, and incrementing the length by 2 is wrong. You can replace those three lines with just this:

```
echoStringLen = strlen(echoString);
```

Comment: When I comment the line with the recv() function, the program works just fine, but when I uncomment it, the segmentation fault are back

Comment: Have you tried allocating memory for storing the user input?

Comment: BTW, it's not uncommon for an error such as this to manifest itself elsewhere in a program. Compiling and running your code on my machine segfaults in `cin >> tempString;`, so that's definitely a problem.