# ssize_t data type in XDR for RPC

Tags: posix, rpc, idl, xdr, sunrpc

I am writing an RPC application. I need to use ssize_t data type in the C portion and it needs to be sent over the wire. What should I represent ssize_t as in the IDL? I can cast it to int but I want to know the correct way to do it than just casting to int, not sure if that is the correct way.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224655/using-ssize-t-vs-int) is what you want.

Comment: @Pushkin I dont have an option to not use ssize_t. its coming me to from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Xdr type **int** (IOW, you should use hyper) represents 32 bit integer. Check [ONC+ Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E35597/xdrproto-31244.html)  for details.