# Alternative to ssize_t on POSIX-unconformant systems

Tags: c, posix

I'm writing a program involving network I/O, so `send` and `recv` are used, which are POSIX functions. They return a `ssize_t`, which is POSIX-specific too.
The wrappers look like this ATM:

```
ssize_t sock_send(int sock, const void* msg, size_t len) {
    return send(sock, msg, len, 0);
}
```

Even though I'm heavily depending on POSIX in my current implementation, I want to make the interface stick closely to the standard because I am planning on writing a Windows implementation later, where POSIX isn't necessarily available (dammit, Windows!).

What would be a good substitution for `ssize_t` as specified by the C11 standard? Perhaps `ptrdiff_t`?
Or how should I approach this issue otherwise?

Comment: Why not just nick the typedef for `ssize_t`?

Comment: Just use ssize_t. If you're on a platform that doesn't have it, define it

Comment: See [Using ssize_t vs int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19224655/2410359) - possible dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the type `ssize_t` is not defined, you can just define it yourself. It is supposed to be a `signed` type with the same size as `size_t`.  Technically, the type `ptrdiff_t` should not be smaller than `size_t`, but it could be larger to accommodate for the larger range.

Here is a portable way to define it:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if SIZE_MAX == UINT_MAX
typedef int ssize_t;        /* common 32 bit case */
#define SSIZE_MIN  INT_MIN
#define SSIZE_MAX  INT_MAX
#elif SIZE_MAX == ULONG_MAX
typedef long ssize_t;       /* linux 64 bits */
#define SSIZE_MIN  LONG_MIN
#define SSIZE_MAX  LONG_MAX
#elif SIZE_MAX == ULLONG_MAX
typedef long long ssize_t;  /* windows 64 bits */
#define SSIZE_MIN  LLONG_MIN
#define SSIZE_MAX  LLONG_MAX
#elif SIZE_MAX == USHRT_MAX
typedef short ssize_t;      /* is this even possible? */
#define SSIZE_MIN  SHRT_MIN
#define SSIZE_MAX  SHRT_MAX
#elif SIZE_MAX == UINTMAX_MAX
typedef intmax_t ssize_t;  /* last resort, chux suggestion */
#define SSIZE_MIN  INTMAX_MIN
#define SSIZE_MAX  INTMAX_MAX
#else
#error platform has exotic SIZE_MAX
#endif
```

Comment: I know at least one platform where this fails: On MSP430X microcontrollers, some toolchains (notably recent versions of the gcc toolchain) use an `uint20_t` for `size_t` and an `int20_t` for `ssize_t`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: how many bits for the standard types `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long`?

Comment: @chrqlie 8, 16, 16, 32, 64. `uintptr_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `intptr_t`, `size_t`, and `ssize_t` all have 20 bit though.

Comment: @FUZxxl: then indeed the type `ssize_t` cannot be inferred from `SIZE_MAX` and must be had coded.

Comment: When you wrote "ptrdiff_t should not be smaller than size_t" don't you mean "ptrdiff_t should not be smaller than ssize_t" ?

Comment: I mean this: `ptrdiff_t` is a signed type, so you could define `ssize_t` as an alias to `ptrdiff_t` but on some architectures you might get a type larger than `size_t`, that is `sizeof(ptrdiff_t) > sizeof(size_t)`, which is not intended.  The problem is you cannot test if `sizeof(ptrdiff_t) == sizeof(size_t)` at the preprocessor level, so you must test numeric values as posted in the answer.

Comment: why use architectures where the number of the native integer bits are not a power of 2? actually, why did they do it? to abuse developers?

Comment: The "is this even possible?" is possible with 16-bit systems that have 32-bit int.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I guess it is possible in theory, but I have never come across an architecture with this combination. Have you?

Comment: I might have, I'm not sure.

Comment: "It is supposed to be a signed type with the same size as size_t" seems common, yet I find no spec support for that.  [The implementation shall support ... environments in which the widths of ... ssize_t, ... are no greater than the width of type long](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) maybe useful.

Comment: @fuz `uint20_t` and 8-bit `char` looks non-compliant as `uintN_t` and `char` should not have padding and bit width of 20 is not a multiple of bit width of 8.  Hmmm.

Comment: chqrlie, The `#if SIZE_MAX == UINT_MAX` approach is a reasonable one - UV.  Within that _if_ tree, useful to include defines for `SSIZE_MIN` and  `SSIZE_MAX`.  For pedantic future growth,I'd include `#elif SIZE_MAX == UINTMAX_MAX`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good suggestions, answer amended.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True, that! They should have called it `__uint20_t` or something similar.

Comment: This line; `typedef uintmax_t ssize_t;` defines it as unsigned. Shouldn't that be a signed version?

Comment: @Tieske: good point! I am amazed it took 3 years for someone to spot this. Thank you