# What return value to use for `read()`?

Tags: c, types, posix, systypes.h

I've noticed that several times to check the return value of `read()` it's used the type `int`, but checking on *man* I noticed that `read()` returns a value of type `ssize_t` instead.  <strike>I got that "in general" int is supposed to be bigger than ssize_t and that's why we don't occur in a error. But my question is:</strike>  **Is there a reason to use `int` instead of `ssize_t`?** Shouldn't it be a best practice to use `ssize_t`?

Example code:

```
int x;
//ssiz_t x;
x = read(fd, &a, sizeof(a));
if (x == sizeof(a))
    // all is fine
if (x == -1)
    // Error while reading file
if (x == 0)
    // Unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Typing 3 chars instead of 7? :)

Comment: Sorry @Marian , I don't understand what are you talking about!

Comment: `int` is a 3 character token, whilst `ssize_t` is 7.

Comment: "*`int` is supposed to be bigger than `ssize_t`*", no, in general it isn't, at least not for the positive part.

Comment: *"Shouldn't it be a best practice to use ssize_t"* - Using exact types whenever possible is indeed a good practice. And you should embrace it whenever you can.

Comment: Oh, I better correct my question so! ^^' So... how is having less characters available a good thing? Shouldn't *everybody* use `ssize_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: Do not change your question after comments/answers had been given, as this might render the latter un-understandable. I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ssize\_t vs int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224655/using-ssize-t-vs-int)

Comment: Just FYI, the first `s` in `ssize_t` stands for `signed`. It's a size that can be negative. The special types (like `size_t` and `ssize_t` and many others) carries with them more *semantic* information. Declaring a variable as a `ssize_t` you tell the reader of the code what the purpose of the variable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got that "in general"  int is supposed to be bigger than ssize_t and that's why we don't occur in a error.

That's not true. There's no absolutely no reason whatsoever for that assumption to be true.

> is there a reason to use int instead of ssize_t? Shouldn't it be a best practice to use ssize_t?

Yes. Use `ssize_t` for storing `read()`'s return.

In most of the your use cases, `read()` might be handling bytes that can be handled by an `int`. Hence, you probably never encountered any problems using `int`. But that's no reason to prefer `int` over `ssize_t`. Always use the right types.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question deleting the wrong assumption.

Comment: But fundamentally the answer is the same: always use correct types for storing the return value of functions as documented. "Shouldn't everybody use ssize_t instead of int?" - Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it be a best practice to use `ssize_t`?

Yes.

In general use whatever type a function is defined to return.

---

> `int` is supposed to be bigger than `ssize_t`

No, in general it isn't, at least not for the positive part.

From the [POSIX documenation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> The type **`ssize_t`** shall be capable of storing values at least in the range [`-1`, {`SSIZE_MAX`}].